# (If else) targeting specific objects in json file with python

Tags: python, json, twitter

I have a json file that contains twitter data and looks like this:

```
{

    "text": "ABC

}
```

For some tweets, there is additional information:

```
{

    "text": "ABC,
    "extended_text": {
        "full_text": "ABCDEFG }
}
```

Now I want to preprocess the text for tokenization. So far I defined the preprocess and now I want to run it.

```
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
```

How do I create an if-else statement that targets the 'full_text' if available and if not just proceeds with the available 'text'?

I'm very new to coding. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused as for why are you parsing the file line by line (and based on the info you provided I'm surprised it even works, *if* it is working).

As for the `if`, you can simply check if the key exists, or assume it exists and handle the consequence if it doesn't.

```
with open('test.json') as f:  # no need to provide 'r' for mode, it is the default
    data = json.load(f)  # parsing the whole file at once

for tweet in data:
    extended_text = tweet.get('extended_text')
    if extended_text:
        full_text = extended_text.get('full_text')
        if full_text:  # this check may or may not be needed,
                       #  depending on the structure of the file
            pass  # handle full_text 
    else:  # no 'extended_text' key
        text = tweet.get('text')
```

Using [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) eliminates the need to use `try ... except KeyError`. It will return a default value (in this case `None`) if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you sure that using `.get()` is actually simplifying this, especially in the case that "extended_text" exists and "full_text" may not?

Surely would be easier to just `try ... except` on `text = tweet["extended_text"]["full_text"]`?

Comment: @Bilkokuya Maybe, and maybe not, which is why I've included the comment "# this check may or may not be needed depending on the structure of the file". I don't believe in copy-paste answers. Instead I believe in pointing askers in the correct direction and expect them to think and change the code I provide to fit their needs

Comment: I generally agree against copy/paste answers - I don't have any issue with that at all; I just don't feel the direction they are being pointed in isn't a great one (using multiple `.get()` with conditional statements vs a single `try ... except` block)

Comment: @Bilkokuya Then nothing is stopping you from posting your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have elements that may or may not exist in a dictionary (or similar object, such as your loaded json data), the two approaches to look at are either:

`value = myDict.get("key", default)` which returns the value if `key` exists in your dictionary or `default` if it doesn't. If you don't provide a default, it will return `None`.

or

```
try:
   value = myDict["key"]
except KeyError:
   # do some error catching here, or ignore it
   pass
```

In this case, accessing the key in `myDict` will cause a `KeyError` if it does not exist. If the logic is simple and you just want to use a default if the key does not exist - I'd highly recommend using the first approach: `.get()`, however if you do anything more complex than that, such as checking keys first - it often becomes easier to do so with the `try ... except` block.

In your specific case, I'd recommend using the `try ... except` block, as you can directly try to access the `full_text` property, and if that doesn't exist - use the `text` property.

```
try:
    text = data["extended_text"]["full_text"]
except KeyError:
    text = data["text"]
# do whatever you wanted to do with the text after here
```

In this example, if the property `full_text` is not available, you will catch a `KeyError` and then retrieve the value `text` instead. Otherwise you will get the value of `full_text`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. I went with .get, I'll try yours when I have some extra time on my hand. Thanks!